# How can i open and close my script

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, onclick

Once I execute `#menu-toggle` with the the button  `Close Menu` the button `Touggle Menu` wont work and would not open the menu again as i want it to do it.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>

<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<meta name="description" content="">
<meta name="author" content="">

<title>Simple Sidebar - Start Bootstrap Template</title>

<!-- Bootstrap Core CSS -->
<link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<!-- Custom CSS -->
<link href="css/simple-sidebar.css" rel="stylesheet">

<!-- HTML5 Shim and Respond.js IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
<!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
    <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/html5shiv/3.7.0/html5shiv.js"></script>
    <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/respond.js/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
<![endif]-->

 </head>

 <body>

<div id="wrapper">

    <!-- Sidebar -->
    <div id="sidebar-wrapper">
        <ul class="sidebar-nav">
            <li class="sidebar-brand">
                <a href="#">
                    <img src="uaalogo.png"  width="200" height="50" > 
                </a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#">Dashboard</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#">Shortcuts</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#">Overview</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#">Events</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#">About</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#">Services</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                 <a href="#menu-toggle" class="btn btn-default" id="menu-toggle">Close Menu</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <!-- /#sidebar-wrapper -->

    <!-- Page Content -->
    <div id="page-content-wrapper">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-12">
                    <h1>Simple Sidebar</h1>

                    <p>Make sure to keep all page content within the <code>#page-content-wrapper</code>.</p>
                     <a href="#menu-toggle" class="btn btn-default" id="menu-toggle">Toggle Menu</a>

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- /#page-content-wrapper -->

</div>
<!-- /#wrapper -->

<!-- jQuery -->
<script src="js/jquery.js"></script>

<!-- Bootstrap Core JavaScript -->
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<!-- Menu Toggle Script -->
<script>

     $("#menu-toggle").click(function(e) {

    $("#wrapper").toggleClass("toggled");
});

</script>
```

Comment: do you try wrap the code inside document ready

Comment: @IfrahimHernandez http://jsfiddle.net

Comment: paste your basic related HTML/CSS/Jquery code here ... http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: Change both `id="menu-toggle"` to `class="menu-toggle"` and then `$(".menu-toggle").click(`

Answer (score 2):

Having 2 elements with the same ID is not valid html according to the W3C specification.

When your CSS selector only has an ID selector (and is not used on a specific context), jQuery uses the native `document.getElementById` method, which returns only the first element with that ID.
so only one of `menu-toggle` is bound with click function. You should use two IDs' for two buttons or use class selector for on click function. Here is the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/36rxh261/)